# how to deal with <s:complexType> and <s:sequence> in node-soap?

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, node-soap

I'm developing a SOAP client that needs to call a SOAP method which is defined as follows:

[image]

The documentation for that method expects the following structure for the "geraet" items:

[image]

How should I call my node-soap method so that the correct SOAP request is being sent?

I've tried this way (and numerous alternatives):

```
client.insUpGeraet({
  geraet: {
    Geraete: {
      Geraet: [ {...}, {...}, ... ]
    },
  }
});
```

...however this just creates an empty `geraet` node and `node-soap` apparently discards the rest:

[image]

A correct request should look like this (debug output of another client):

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you to switch to strong-soap library its a complete rewrite of node-soap or if the SOAP request or security is not standart better use https://github.com/yaronn/ws.js for SOAP requests

Comment: @sytolk: tried with `strong-soap` but it fails to set the proper namespace [as documented here](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-soap/issues/63#issue-196093562). Will probably resort to make my own SOAP requests, without any lib...

Answer (score 0):

The `createclient` has an option `namespaceArrayElements`. This should be set to `false`. I think this is what you're referring to.

For reference: https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#soapcreateclienturl-options-callback---create-a-new-soap-client-from-a-wsdl-url-also-supports-a-local-filesystem-path